# Best way to run local server using c or c++

Tags: c++, c, https, localhost, localserver

I'm wanting to create a local server on my laptop that runs on c or c++ for the sake of web development. I'm building a website and the backend will run on c or c++ so I'm wanting my development environment to be very similar to the production environment. I've never done anything like this before. What's the best way to go about this? Also if I use https protocol, does that make it 'safe'? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to install lampp or xampp and use apache. On linux you are going to install your C programs as *.cgi in your directory /opt/lampp/cgi-bin , first get your install to work then you can worry about making it secure, most people will tell you to use PHP and/or other languages instead of C. There is no reason not to use C if you like it. It works fine.

Comment: Yes no problem , on windows look for Xampp

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't know I could use c or c++ with xampp. Thanks